# Python replacement for goto

Tags: python, goto, finally

Suppose I have a function that does a bunch of work in steps. Between each step I want to either continue or skip the rest of the steps. After the work is done an additional block of code should always be executed. I know that I could use try + finally for that, but it is not really error related and I don't want to throw fake exceptions. The way I do this right now is by abusing an infinite while loop with break statements to achieve some kind of goto. My question is: Is there a more idiomatic way than this?

```
# ugly goto hack
while True:
  do_work()

  if condition:
    break

  do_more_work()
  
  if condition:
    break

  do_even_more_work()

  if condition:
    break

  #....

  break

do_some_final_work()
```

Comment: Could you update your question with some more realistic function calls and checks for the exit condition? If it is as simple as you currently show, then the function names could be put in a collection and a `for` loop could iterate over them.

Comment: Just FYI, there are [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) used for this purpose: `GeneratorExit`, `StopIteration`, `StopAsyncIteration`, etc. Exceptions are not just errors.

Comment: You can place the while-body (without the `while` itself) in a function and use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: it would look like a goto if you could access directly `do_more_work` in your loop. depending on the condition it could break before getting there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is nested `if` statements, reversing the conditions.

```
do_work()

if not condition:
    do_more_work()

    if not condition:
        do_even_more_work()

        if not condition:
            # ...

do_some_final_work()
```

To avoid deep nesting like this, you can use a status variable. We use the following pattern in code that executes a series of steps until some kind of failure happens. This often appears when performing a series of validations.

```
error = False
# code that executes do_work() and sets error = True if it fails

if not error:
    # code that executes do_more_work() and sets error = True if it fails

if not error:
    # code that executes do_even_more_work() and sets error = True if it fails

# ...

do_some_final_work()
```

`error` could also be an error message rather than just a boolean.